# Agregating and summing values in groups of adjacent months (xslt 1.0)

Tags: xslt, sum, grouping, xslt-1.0

I'm new to xslt and I've problem. There's the xml set of unsorted data like this:

```
<values>
    
    <periodData>
        <periodDate>2020-07-01</periodDate> <!-- date, but signifitiant is 2020-07 -->
        <periodValue>100.10</periodValue> <!-- decimal -->
    </periodData>
    
    <periodData>
        <periodDate>2020-05-01</periodDate>
        <periodValue>500.00</periodValue>
    </periodData>
    
    <periodData>
        <periodDate>2019-12-01</periodDate>
        <periodValue>0.05</periodValue>
    </periodData>
    
    <periodData>
        <periodDate>2020-01-01</periodDate>
        <periodValue>100.00</periodValue>
    </periodData>
    
    <periodData>
        <periodDate>2020-08-01</periodDate>
        <periodValue>100.01</periodValue>
    </periodData>
    
    <periodData>
        <periodDate>2019-12-01</periodDate>
        <periodValue>101.00</periodValue>
    </periodData>
    
    <periodData>
        <periodDate>2020-02-01</periodDate>
        <periodValue>110.00</periodValue>
    </periodData>

</values>
```

I need to display (using xslt 1.0) sorted groups of perionds, grouped by adjacent months, showing minimum and maximum dates in a group, and values summed in each group.
Like this:

```
Period: 2019-12-01 - 2020-02-01, Sum: 311.05

Period: 2020-05-01 - 2020-05-01, Sum: 500.00

Period: 2020-07-01 - 2020-08-01, Sum: 200.11
```

The main problem is to identify groups of adjacent months and sum values in each group then.

Could you help, please?

Comment: This is an awful lot of work, esp. since you have multiple `periodData` nodes with the same `periodDate`. I would start by grouping these together. Then sort the resulting nodes and tag them with something like  `12*$year + $month - 1 - position()`. Finally, group by the tag. Alternatively, you could try doing "sibling recursion" - but even for this you would have to do a preliminary pass of sorting.

Comment: Your algorithm is great, thank you very much! But, as I'm not familiar with more complex xslt functions, I have almost no idea how to write working xslt 1.0 code. Use Muenchian Grouping? How? Use two keys? Could you or somebody else write this piece of code, or point me how to use keys and grouping? I've wrote some code based on Muenchian Grouping (using examle I've found), but I don't understand it well enough to be able to use it more complicated way, especialy using two or more keys...

Comment: I am not going to write your code for you (not for free, anyway). I suggest you take it one step at a time. Yes, you need Muenchian grouping for steps #1 and #3. It is explained well here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html